# Stack order problem: Show element above siblings first child and below siblings second child

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

I have the following code and want to show the **title string over the (orange) map div, but under the (olive) overlay div**. My attempts at z-indexing (see code below) did not work. What am I missing here? (I left the transforms in the css code as they might alter the stack order.)

```css
body,
.root {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  transition: 1s ease;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.map {
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  top: 0;
  left: 5%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 1s ease;
  background-color: olive;
  z-index: 100;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="root">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="map">.</div>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">Title Title Title Title</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

styling the main tag is not needed since you intend to make the class('title') be under the overlay tag but above the class('map')

here is a solution to fix the problem:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.root {
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.map {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 60%;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  top: 0;
  left: 5%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 1s ease;
  background-color: olive;
  z-index: 10;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Nah, I do need to keep the transform styling of the main tag (or, if there is not simpler way, replicate its functionality in JS). Since I can't post my full project here, I did not include the code pushing out main and sliding in other elements. That's what I meant by saying "I left the transforms in the css code".